# How to convert PDF or SATO to ZEBRA ZPL format

Tags: pdf, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

Need to convert a multi-pages `PDF` to print in `Zebra` printer.

A solution in `.NET C#` would be great.

2 input options: `SATO` format or `PDF` format

Two options I see:

1. Convert the `PDF` Pages to `BMP` Image then print it in a `Zebra` printer, but how to separate the `PDF` Pages into multiple `BMP` images?

Researching I found that ZEBRA has a PDF converter in this link, but the documentation is poor and does not explain properly.

https://www.zebra.com/ap/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/pdf-virtual-device.html

https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/solutions-verticals/product/Software/Printer%20Software/Link-OS/GENERAL/pdf-usecase.pdf

2. Convert the `SATO` commands to `ZPL` commands (I couldn't find anything like that on the web, and this would be the perfect solution.)

https://www.satoaustralia.com/products/printers.aspx

Any ideas how to do it or any link that helps to find the solution or tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That PDF driver that Zebra sells allows you to use a ZPL command to send a PDF file to the printer like you would an image. It's not a PDF converter, but rather lets the printer receive and process a PDF document